# complex sql query to get data for JIT spacetree

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to build json string for a spacetree like below :-
http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Spacetree/example2.code.html

Currently I am using below query :-

```
SELECT BT.ParentID,BT.CustomerID,CU.firstname 
from BinaryTree BT INNER JOIN Customers CU on BT.CustomerID=CU.CustomerID
WHERE [ParentID] = 2
ORDER BY BT.ParentID,BT.CustomerID
```

It is returning result as follows :-

```
ParentID   CustomerID  firstname
     2      100176         Bill
     2      115468        will
```

Means here 2 is root element of tree and 100176,115468 are child elements.
But these child nodes 100176 and 115468 also have some child nodes, means these are root/parentnode for some other children. Means query would be :-

```
SELECT BT.ParentID,BT.CustomerID,CU.firstname 
from BinaryTree BT INNER JOIN Customers CU on BT.CustomerID=CU.CustomerID
WHERE [ParentID] = 100176
ORDER BY BT.ParentID,BT.CustomerID
```

and result for 100176 :-

```
 ParentID   CustomerID  firstname
   100176    100222       J
   100176    348645       K
```

and

```
SELECT BT.ParentID,BT.CustomerID,CU.firstname 
from BinaryTree BT INNER JOIN Customers CU on BT.CustomerID=CU.CustomerID
WHERE [ParentID] = 115468        
ORDER BY BT.ParentID,BT.CustomerID
```

and result for 115468 :-

```
 ParentID   CustomerID  firstname
  115468     154756       D
  115468     348480       L
```

But I need all the parents and children in one query like :-

```
 ParentID   CustomerID  firstname
    2        100176       Bill
    2        115468       will
  100176     100222       J
  100176     348645       K
  115468     154756       D
  115468     348480       L
```

Children of 100176 and 115468 can also have child nodes, so these should also be result for 100222,348645 in above result.

Can any body help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH CustomerTree AS (
    SELECT ParentID
          ,CustomerID
          ,0 AS Level
    FROM BinaryTree
    WHERE ParentID = 2
  UNION ALL
    SELECT BinaryTree.ParentID
          ,BinaryTree.CustomerID
          ,CustomerTree.Level + 1 AS Level
    FROM BinaryTree
         INNER JOIN CustomerTree
            ON BinaryTree.ParentID = CustomerTree.CustomerID
)
SELECT CustomerTree.ParentID
      ,CustomerTree.CustomerId
      ,Customers.FirstName
FROM CustomerTree
     INNER JOIN Customers
         ON CustomerTree.CustomerID = Customers.CustomerID
```